# Turn off GitHub enterprise dark mode in Firefox

Tags: github, firefox, lightmode

I am desperately looking for options to turn off the dark mode on the GitHub pages.  It is painful to see dark screens in the daytime.

I tried adding plugins to Firefox to disable the darkening, but the plugins are not useful.

Screenshot attached below.  Greatly appreciate any pointers.

[image]

Comment: The small switch on the upper-right corner of the profile page?

Comment: @kofemann Thank you very very much.  I see that option now after logging in to my profile.